# Apple's Reminders app: How do you deal with completed tasks?

Tags: reminders

I just realised that I've never used Apple's app Reminders as it would deserve to be used, because I've never completely understood his way of managing completed tasks.

I mean:

- I create a reminder.
- I complete it and it disappear.
- It doesn't really disappear, it's just hidden in the completed list.

If I would use Reminders for every thing I'd need it, I would accumulate thousands of completed tasks every year. What's the point of keeping all them there?

Should I cancel them manually? But should I cancel them 1 by 1, or all together in one shot? Why not setting a default cancellation time, like Notes or vocals on iMessage.

Or should I keep them all as a memory? Wouldn't them, slowly slowly, fill up my 5gb free iCloud storage?

Am I missing something? What's your way of dealing with completed tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear them out, either only older than a month or all tasks.

On macOS, at the top of the list under the title you'll see "X Completed • Clear". You can click Clear and you'll get asked which ones you want to delete.

On iOS, click the (•••) menu and "Show Completed," then you'll see the same "X Completed • Clear" text under the title. Clicking it will show the same menu as on macOS.

You will not easily fill up your iCloud Storage. Simply clear the list every once in a while and you'll never get close.